# adapting a start (shell?) script for Eclipse to MacOS (Windows and Linux examples given)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, shell

I'm trying to follow an instruction on how to place versions of Eclipse and OpenJDK in a separate folder and run them by executing a small program named eclipsestart. We are working with an older JDK version and the goal is to have this separate from other Java versions already installed and to use the same environment as everyone else in the class.

This is the setup of the folder:

- Eclipse
- jdk1.8 (openJDK 8)
- workspace (where all java files will be stored)
- eclipsestart.txt

I  have examples of what the code in eclipsestart looks like for Windows and Linux operating systems, but don't know how to adapt the code for macOS Catalina.

Code for Windows:

```
start eclipse\\eclipse.exe -vm "jdk1.8\\jre\\bin\\javaw.exe" -data "workspace"
```

--> write code in txt-file and change name to eclipsestart.cmd

Code for Linux:

```
#!/bin/sh
./eclipse/eclipse -vm jdk1.8/jre/bin/java -data workspace -showlocation &
```

--> write code in txt-file and make file executable by „chmod +x eclipsestart“

Can anyone help me to adapt this small script to its equivalent for MacOS?

I think I should keep most of the Linux version.

I changed the filename to eclipsestart.sh and executed the following in Terminal:

```
chmod u+x eclipsestart.sh 
eclipsestart.sh
```

It starts running but tells me

```
./eclipsestart.sh: line 2: ./eclipse/eclipse: No such file or directory
```

I saw that there is a file ./eclipse/eclipse.ini , so I changed eclipsestart.sh accordingly. I could also see that the directory for java in jdk1.8 is different from the Linux one, so changed that as well:

```
    #!/bin/sh
./eclipse/eclipse.ini -vm jdk1.8/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -data workspace -showlocation &
```

Unfortunately I get

```
./eclipsestart.sh: line 2: ./eclipse/eclipse.ini: Permission denied
```

Does it make sense to add the *.ini? Or should I be looking for another file? Can I work around the "permission denied"-error?

Comment: To run on macOS 12 you need a very recent version of Eclipse and these require at least Java 11.

Comment: I'm on macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina)

Comment: .ini files are configuration, you cannot execute them. After installing, I can just open Eclipse like any other macos app. I don't know why you need a script.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to add the .ini file, it is for startup options. You need the native launcher binary, the equivalent of `eclipse/eclipse` on Linux.

The native launcher binary on macOS is packaged as `Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse`. You can list properly installed JREs using `/usr/libexec/java_home`; I suggest running it with `--help`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm trying to run an older Java version (JDK 8) independently of any software installed on my Mac - with everything packaged in a folder that can be transferred and run from any Mac. Is that feasible? I downloaded jdk8 and eclipse as .tar.gz . I have the downloaded files in a separate folder and want to initialise them with help of the script mentioned above that I need help on. I couldn't find Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse in the Eclipse file I downloaded. Is that a sign I don't have the correct file?

Comment: I obviously don't have much of a clue :-) , but I was able to find the launcher binary after all and it tries to open, but the path to JRE/JDK seems to be wrong

Comment: `find {jdkroot} -perm +700 -name java`

Comment: Thanks! I input that in Terminal, but get the following error:  find: {jdkroot}: No such file or directory

Comment: And with `/usr/libexec/java_home` :
`Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.` But I understood that it does not need to be installed, as long as I can get the script to execute the correct file from the JDK-folder as VM (euqivalents to this file in Windows being `"jdk1.8\\jre\\bin\\javaw.exe"` and in Linux `jdk1.8/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java`)

Comment: In general, your MacOS script should be pretty similar to the Linux one. You mustn't make assumptions about where the script is run from and you must ensure, in light of that, that paths are correct, which will mean in practice that they should be absolute

Comment: *Thanks! I input that in Terminal, but get the following error: find: {jdkroot}: No such file or directory*
You misinterpreted the comment. The curly-braced token is a placeholder, and not to be taken literally. Personally, to avoid doubt, I would do `sudo find / -type f -name java 2>/dev/null`. You can post what that gives